# Add unpacked files to resulting jar (MAVEN)

Tags: maven, jar, maven-dependency-plugin

I am a bit newbie using maven so I am struggling to achieve something that seems to be simple.

I am unpacking a dependency like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <includes>**/*.jar</includes>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

[Source](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html)

I see the jar files in my targetDirectory/alternateLocation but how can I add them to the final jar?

Comment: Why are you unpackaging  dependencies ? What is the purpose? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Basically, we have a corporate jar file that contains other files required to create a new artifact. This new artifact will be a OSGi wrapper for the initial corporate jar. Will use this to generate the OSGi bundle: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html